# Subtract number of days from sysdate using variable oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

I am creating a trigger to perform an insert in with a date in the past.

```
days_trans := dbms_random.value(14,90);
time_avail := sysdate - interval ':days_trans' day;
```

This gives me

`PLS-00166: bad format for date, time, timestamp or interval literal`

How should I subtract the variable constant?

Comment: Just use `time_avail := sysdate - days_trans;`. A string `:days_trans` is not allowed in interval literals, for a correct syntax please see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i38598). BTW, dbms_random.vaue gives floating point value, not integer, it might be better to trunc or round that number, becaus you can get suprising results.

Comment: Thanks. The trunc function has been quite helpful also.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot bind variables to literals. `INTERVAL` are used with `TIMESTAMP`, use either

```
time_avail := sysdate - days_trans;
```

or

```
time_avail := systimestamp - days_trans * interval '1' day;
```

Comment: The simple arithmetical approach is the better fit for the OP's requirement